# In Snowflake, you cannot reference a shared view from a function if you want to share that function, but you can reference a shared function?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-sharing

I define a secure function in account A that properly references a secure view from account B. When I try to share this function through a data share, it fails with "*SQL compilation error: A view or function being shared cannot reference objects from other databases.*"

However, if I create a wrapper function around the secure view in account B, and I refer to this function instead in account A, it works. The secure view could be as simple as "SELECT 1", so I don't need to care about REFERENCE_USAGE.

Is this expected behavior?

Simplified code:

```
create or replace secure function db_b.public.func_b()
  returns number
as 'select top 1 val from db_a.public.view_a';

-- this fails with the error described
grant usage on function db_b.public.func_b() to share share_b;
```

But if I define in B:

```
create or replace secure function db_a.public.func_a()
  returns number
as 'select top 1 val from db_a.public.view_a';
```

then I can use in A:

```
create or replace secure function db_b.public.func_b()
  returns number
as 'select db_a.public.func_a()';

-- this works now!
grant usage on function db_b.public.func_b() to share share_b;
```

This doesn't work:

[image]

But this does:

[image]

Comment: that does seem inconsistent. hmm, was mixing CREATE PROCEDURE options with CREATE FUNCTION

Comment: It seems it passes the security check at creation, but does it actually work? Are you able to call the function successfully?

Comment: yes, it works fine as well.

Comment: Just so you know, this doesn't work anymore, it looks like it was a loophole that got fixed.